# How to overwrite Autofac-injected service in integration tests

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, integration-testing

The scenario is quite simple. I register a service normally, with Autofac, for my standard program run, but for my integration tests I'd like to overwrite that implementation with a mock and so I do as they tell in various tutorials on the internet. In my Program.cs file, among other, I have the below lines:

```
builder.Host
    .ConfigureContainer<ContainerBuilder>(
        builder => builder
            .RegisterModule(new ApplicationModule())
            .RegisterModule(new InfrastructureModule())
            .RegisterModule(new WebApiModule()));
```

Then I define my TestAppBase class as follows:

```
public abstract class TestAppBase<TProgram, TContext> : WebApplicationFactory<TProgram> 
    where TContext : DbContext
    where TProgram : class
{
    private IServiceScope _scope;

    private readonly Guid _dbGuid;
    private readonly bool _reuseScope = true;
    private readonly Action<IServiceCollection> _customization;
    private readonly Dictionary<string, string> _configurationOverrides;

    public TContext DbContext => RequestScope().ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<TContext>();

    public Requests Requests => RequestScope().ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<Requests>().WithClient(CreateClient());

    protected TestAppBase(Action<IServiceCollection> customization, Dictionary<string, string> configurationOverrides)
    {
        ClientOptions.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
        _customization = customization;
        _configurationOverrides = configurationOverrides;
        _scope = base.Services.CreateAsyncScope();
        _dbGuid = Guid.NewGuid();
    }

    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        base.ConfigureWebHost(builder);
        builder
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((builder, configurationBuilder) => configurationBuilder.AddInMemoryCollection(_configurationOverrides!))
            .ConfigureServices(services =>
            {
            })
            .ConfigureTestServices(services =>
            {
                var descriptor = services.SingleOrDefault(d => d.ServiceType == typeof(DbContextOptions<TContext>));

                if (descriptor != null)
                    services.Remove(descriptor);

                services.AddDbContext<TContext>(config => config.UseInMemoryDatabase(_dbGuid.ToString()));
                services.AddSingleton<Requests>();

                _customization(services);
            });
    }

    protected IServiceScope RequestScope()
    {
        if (!_reuseScope)
        {
            _scope.Dispose();
            _scope = Services.CreateScope();
        }

        return _scope;
    }
}
```

As you can see, it's being passed the `customization` argument later invoked in the `ConfigureTestServices` method.
The integration test app class is defined as follows:

```
internal class ProducerTestApp : TestAppBase<Program, Context>
{
    public ProducerTestApp(
        Action<IServiceCollection> customization, 
        Dictionary<string, string> configurationOverrides) : base(customization, configurationOverrides)
    { }

    public static ProducerTestApp CreateInstance()
    {
        var sut = new ProducerTestApp(services => 
        {
            var desc = services.SingleOrDefault(d => d.ServiceType == typeof(IMyService));

            if (desc != null)
                services.Remove(desc);

            services.AddSingleton<IMyService, MockMyService>();
            services.BuildServiceProvider();
        }, 
        new Dictionary<string, string>(){});

        return sut;
    }
}
```

When I put breakpoints in the `ProducerTestApp` class, the following happens:

1. `desc` is null and when I inspect `services` contents in debug mode there's actually no matching service there. It's weird, because it's injected normally.
2. If in my `Program.cs` file I comment out services registration and leave the rest as is, I can see `MockMyService` being actually registered and used.

So the question is how do I preserve the standard services registration that's there in the `Program.cs` file but at the same time how do I overwrite already registered services in the `ProducerTestApp` class?

Answer (score -1):

In your case I read it again and detailed on bigger monitor not just on phone and I can offer these recommendations only:

1. Service Lifetime: The lifetime of the service could be an issue. When you register your service with AddSingleton(), it will only be created once for the lifetime of your test app. However, if your service is being resolved in a scope where a different instance was already created (for example, if the original service was registered as scoped or transient), then the new singleton won't be used. In your test, try registering your service with the same lifetime as in your production code.
2. Service Registration Order: In general, the last registration wins. If there's another registration for the same service happening after your test registration, your test service won't be used. Make sure there are no additional registrations after your test registration.
3. ContainerBuilder vs IServiceCollection: There might be a conflict between services registered in Autofac's ContainerBuilder and Microsoft's built-in IServiceCollection. You're trying to remove a service from IServiceCollection and replace it with a mock, but it might still be registered in Autofac's ContainerBuilder. Autofac registrations can't be removed the same way. If the service is registered in Autofac's ContainerBuilder, you would need to overwrite it in the ConfigureContainer method.

It's hard to say definitively without seeing all the registration code. Can you provide more context about how your service is registered in your production code and in your tests?

Also, it may be helpful to log the service registrations and resolutions to understand what's going wrong. Autofac provides ways to track what's happening under the hood, you can use the WhatDoIHave() method or the ContainerBuilder.RegisterCallback() method to output the registrations.

If you continue to experience difficulties, it may be beneficial to isolate this issue in a small, reproducible sample project. This will help to understand if there's something specific in your project causing this behavior.

Comment: Pozdrawiam z Polski ;) Yup, I know this code should work, and when you read closely my code snippets, you'll see I'm doing exactly what you described. Still, it doesn't work :(